# Add selected to only one option

Tags: jquery

I adding selected attribute to select box option. I am suing this code :

```
$("#crop option:selected" ).attr("selected", true);
```

Calling this code in `.onchange`

There are multiple options - so when ever option gets changed it add selected attribute to those options. I can see there are multiple selected options, i just want it be for single.

Comment: Can you please elaborate. Provide a fiddle of what you've done so far maybe?

Comment: You don't need to do it because it happens automatically. Correct me if I am wrong!

Comment: No it don't add selected attribute by its self, Check in inspect element.

Answer (score 0):

An select field add the selected attribut automaticly, you don't need jquery. If you want to allow multiselect, add attribute `multiple` to your `select` tag and if you don't want allow this, remove it.